# How to disable automatic updates of Chrome when run with Selenium?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have an automatic test suite that uses Selenium to control a Chrome browser with a particular version. However Chrome tries to update itself between test runs. How do I prevent Chrome from automatically updating itself?

Comment: See here: https://www.chromium.org/administrators/turning-off-auto-updates/  Alternatively you can set a system environment property to stop ChromeDriver from checking for version match.  ex: in Java:  System.setProperty ("webdriver.chrome.disableBuildCheck", "true");  That may be for Selenium 4.x only... I haven't tested on the old 3.x version.

Comment: Unfortunately that link doesn't give info about disabling updates for Chrome on a Mac. And it's not clear how the Windows instructions (which involve fiddling with the global registry) could be isolated to a test copy of a Chrome browser only, vs applying to every Chrome browser on the same computer.

Comment: FWIW, I managed to find [Google's official instructions for turning off Chrome updates on macOS](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7591084). Unfortunately it appears to apply to all copies of Chrome on the same computer. I'd prefer to limit updates on just a single copy of Chrome used for tests.

Comment: You can use a standalone version/offshoot of Chrome like Slimjet.  I don't think that will auto-update.  (I use that for Chrome v49, which is the last version that is supported for WindowsXP)  Not sure if it suits your needs though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing write permission from the Google Chrome binary appears to prevent it from self-updating, at least on macOS and Linux.

In Python you can do that with code that looks like:

```py
import subprocess

def remove_write_permissions(itempath: str) -> None:
    subprocess.run([
        'chmod',
        '-R',
        'a-w',
        itempath
    ], check=True, capture_output=True)

remove_write_permissions('/Applications/Google Chrome.app')
```

This specific code works on macOS. Similar code works on Linux when you target the Chrome binary. I haven't tested this approach on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Chrome for Testing](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/chrome-for-testing/) instead of regular Chrome. It already has automatic updates disabled.

Note however if you need to run versions of Chrome older than 113 then there is no corresponding Chrome for Testing version.